# sy-datum low and high definitions

Tags: abap, opensql

I have an ABAP program with below sample code which should select data from an SAP table based on a date column.

```
INITIALIZATION. 
select-OPTIONS: so_date FOR sy-datum.  
START-OF-SELECTION. 
so_date-sign = 'I'. 
so_date-option = 'BT'. 
so_date-low = sy-datum. 
so_date-high = '99991231'. 
APPEND so_date.
```

and my select stmt is:

```
select c1,c2,c3 
from <sap_table>
where <date_column> in so_date.
```

I want to know the purpose of setting so_date-high = '99991231' and how it will behave.

Answer (score 4):

`BT` means between. `99991231` is a date in the internal format YYYYMMDD (Year-month-day), it is the 31th december 9999. Your setting of the select option hits any date between today and a date far in the future.

TheG already mentioned: It should be better at `INITIALIZATION`, so your selection is already visible on selection-screen and can be modified if you need it.

```
select-OPTIONS: so_date FOR sy-datum.  
INITIALIZATION. 
  so_date-sign = 'I'. 
  so_date-option = 'BT'. 
  so_date-low = sy-datum. 
  so_date-high = '99991231'. 
  APPEND so_date.
```

Remark: This presetting works only in dialogue, not in batch (but when you call it in batch, you can set the default in the variant for the batch job).

But for this easy default values, you should use the `default`-option of `select-options`:

```
SELECT-OPTIONS: so_date FOR sy-datum DEFAULT sy-datum to '99991231'.
```

Or to say 'everything in the future':

```
SELECT-OPTIONS: so_date FOR sy-datum DEFAULT sy-datum OPTION GE.
```

`GE` means greater equal.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would put the so_date-high = '99991231' under the initialization part so that it is reflected on the selection screen. If the user wants to change the date range then it gives more flexibility for them to change in selection screen. This way the user knows the date range which is being effected on the select statement. It is a good practise to ensure the end user knows the date ranges at work without having to look at the code to find the hardcoded information.

select c1,c2,c3 
from  into table 
where  in so_date.

The above select would pick c1,c3 and c3 fields and put it in the table  where the condition  GE so_date-low and  LE so_date-high is satisfied. 
(LE- Less than or Equal to  ; GE - Greater Than or Equal to )

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Just to be more clear the IN clause in my select should be read as "GE so_date-low and LE so_date-high is satisfied." Does this hold true every time I use the IN clause for dates in my ABAP?